# System.Timers.Timer timer1_Elapsed fired only when debuggin but not when service is installed

Tags: c#, timer

I am newbie to windows service and following is what I am trying. The `System.Timers.Timer timer1_Elapsed`get fired only when I am debugging but when I went for installation nothing get happen. I don't think if I am missing but still I would like to have suggestion/advice from experts and gurus.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("myTestService service started on " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
    double processHour = Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProcessHour"]);
    DateTime dtStartDateTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(processHour);
    DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;
    if (dtNow.Hour>= processHour)
    {
        dtStartDateTime = dtStartDateTime.AddDays(1);
    }
    System.TimeSpan diff = dtStartDateTime.Subtract(dtNow);
    timer1.Interval = diff.TotalMilliseconds;
    this.timer1.Elapsed += timer1_Elapsed;
    this.timer1.Start();
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("myTestService service exit from onStart at" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
}

private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
timer1.Stop();
eventLog1.WriteEntry("myTestService timer1_Elapsed begin on " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
/*some logic*/
}
```

Comment: But `myTestService service started on xxx` is written to the log? Dump the value of `processHour` to the event log; without looking too much at the logic, my assumption would be that config is read from a different place (or default settings used) and that the timer interval is different from what you expect.

Comment: As "Groo" says. Also, consider putting this section in a "Try/Catch" and then adding the Exception message to the event log. I suspect that it's failing before the Timer is fired. Here's a good intro on how to write Windows Services with examples: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106742/Creating-a-simple-Windows-Service

Comment: I've also set default interval property of timer to 10 seconds.

Comment: @Groo you were right it was handling time interval through a formula and that was vary each time. at maximum it took 17 hours of interval. Thank you both for your valuable information